# Why can I run JUnit tests without explicitly setting the classpath?

Tags: java, junit

When I type into command  line:

```
java -cp '.:/usr/share/java/*' junit.textui.TestRunner MyTest
```

versus

```
java junit.textui.TestRunner MyTest
```

The second one works just like the first. Does it mean that the junit.textui package can be found without setting the classpath or it just works?

Comment: It means that the junit.textui package is on your current classpath. Possibly added by something else, since you seem to be surprised at this. You could check what "echo $CLASSPATH" says.

Comment: Thanks! You may post an answer to which I will vote as correct instantly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would mean that the junit.textui package is on your classpath already. To display the current default classpath, you can use "echo $CLASSPATH".

In many cases the default classpath ($CLASSPATH) won't hold every necessary library, so you need to specify them separately with the -cp command line switch, therefore whenever you're creating for example batch files / shell scripts, you should consider that all the required libraries are explicitly specified (i.e. all the libraries not included in the default JDK).